# Impresion con python y win32print

Tags: python, imprimir

Banda, estoy trabajando con imprimir archivos en una impresora local, y por ahí me topé con este código:

```
win32api.ShellExecute (
  0,
  "print",
  file,
  '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),
  ".",
  0
)
```

> Mi pregunta es, **¿qué función cumple ésta sección del código?** 
> **'/d:"%s"' %**

He probado quitando es parte del código y la impresión es exitosa, y sin borrar esa parte del código también la impresión es exitosa.

Comment: El código está especificando usar la impresora por default. Si no lo pones, usa la impresora por default. Por tanto, da igual que lo pongas o no.

Comment: Vale, gracias por la ayuda, he probado buscando en internet algo referente a ello y no encontraba, por eso vine buscando ayuda. Gracias por el dato. ¿Qué recomiendas en mantener o quitarlo? ¿En tu experiencia cómo lo haces?

Answer (score 0):

La expresión completa es

```
'/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ()
```

La primera parte es el formato de edición, separado con un '%' de los valores de reemplazo.

En este caso, el `%s` se reemplaza el resultado de `GetDefaultPrinter()`, que es el nombre de la impresora (como "PRN"), con lo que la expresión completa queda en

```
'/d:"PRN"'
```

La documentación nos dice:

> 7.1.4. Viejo formateo de cadenas
>
> El operador % (módulo) también se puede utilizar para formatear
> cadenas de caracteres. Dados los 'cadena de caracteres' % valores, las
> instancias de % en cadena de caracteres se reemplazan con cero o más
> elementos de valores. Esta operación se conoce comúnmente como
> interpolación de cadenas. Por ejemplo:

```
import math
print('The value of pi is approximately %5.3f.' % math.pi)
The value of pi is approximately 3.142.
```

Esta es una forma vieja de formatear cadenas y ya no se usa.

Comment: Que lastima. Formatear cadenas de la forma nueva es horrible cuando la sintaxis de llaves se usa para otros propositos dentro de la cadena (como expresiones regulares o json). Espero que la comunidad no decida que se volvió completamente inutil...

Comment: Puedes usar f-strings, que para mi gusto son lo mejor.

Comment: Los f-strings tienen el mismo problema, utilizan llaves. Se que se pueden escapar. Pero escaparlas todo el tiempo es horrible...

Comment: @DanteS. Nunca he escapado una llave.

Comment: Tal vez por que nunca tuviste que formatear una expresion regular.

Comment: @DanteS. La experiencia me ha demostrado que es más rápido, claro y simple usar una expresión regular "básica" + código de post-proceso que intentar escribir la expresión regular "perfecta". Tal vez por eso nunca he tenido que escapar nada.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139977/discussion-between-dante-s-and-candid-moe).

Comment: "formato de edición", ¿cómo trabaja eso? si al quitar `'/d:"%s"' %` del código, la impresión es exitosa. En tu experiencia recomiendas ¿mantener o quitar esa parte del código? Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: @CandidMoe he probado formatear con f-string, esta primera sin f-string

`win32api.ShellExecute(
    0,
    'open',
    GSPRINT_PATH,
    '-ghostscript "'+GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH+'" -printer "'+currentprinter+'" '+pdfFile,
    '.',
    0)`

y esta otra con f-string


`win32api.ShellExecute(
    0,
    'open',
    GSPRINT_PATH,
    f'-ghostscript {GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH} -printer {currentprinter} '+pdfFile,
    '.',
    0)`

La primera me ejecuta la impresión con éxito, y la segunda simplemente no ocurre la impresión y tampoco arroja algún error.

¿Qué podría estar mal?